# Change color of option selected - jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-selectors

I want to change the text color of the option that is selected="selected":

```
    <select class="select">
        <option value="--">--</option>
        <option value="2014">2014</option>
        <option value="2013">2013</option>
        <option value="2012" selected="selected">2012</option>
        <option value="2011">2011</option>
    </select>
```

I have been trying with CSS but it seems its not possible:

```
    .select select [selected="selected"]{
        color: #2b2b2b;
    }
```

Any ideas with jQuery?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*I have been trying with CSS but it seems its not possible:*

Because you are targetting the `select` tag and not `option` tag also, that selector means select any `select` element nested inside element having `.select` `class`

```
select option[selected] {
    color: red;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4sT85/)

You are using `class` so you can make a selector like

```
.select option[selected] {
   color: red;
}
```

Comment: It might be my browser but when I change the selected option in the demo, the color does not move to the newly selected option

Comment: @andyb If it's that the case than you will have to use jQuery, CSS will change the `color` of the initial state

Comment: Yeah I guess the requirements aren't clear between if it should be a one-off `selected="selected"` CSS or does it need to be dynamic.

Comment: @andyb Yea, I answered this because OP was trying to style that with CSS, so always first preference to CSS, than comes the jQuery

Comment: I´m using the latest version of Chrome and I don´t see a change in the color of the demo... what could be the problem?

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
$('.select').change(function () {
            $(this).find('option:selected').css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

for changing color of text Use

```
  $(this).find('option:selected').css('color', 'red');
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/RNha5/1/)**

Comment: I tried this on a Chrome on top of a Mac. Didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

LIke this

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zNTqm/446/)**

**js**

```
    $('.select').change(function () {
    $(this).find('option').css('color', '#000000');
    $(this).find('option:selected').css('color', '#ff0000');
}).trigger('change');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
 $('.select option:selected').css('color','#2b2b2b');
```

or if you want to fire the event every time `select` option has been changed, you can do:

```
$('.select').change(function () {
     $(this).find('option:selected').css('color','#2b2b2b');
});
```

or with just plain css:

```
select option:checked {
     color: #2b2b2b;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.select option:checked {
    color: red;
}
```

Not sure about browser compatibility on this one..

Edit: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked