# How to change the font color in a selected option?

Tags: html, css, forms, html-select

I have the following HTML code:

```
<div class="register_account">
    <form>
        <select>
            <option value="null">Select a Country</option>
            <option value="AX">Åland Islands</option>
            <option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
            <option value="AL">Albania</option>
            <option value="DZ">Algeria</option>
        </select>
    </form>
</div>
```

and CSS code:

```
.register_account
{ 
    background: #0023C4;
    width:62%;
    padding:1.5%;
}

.register_account form select
{ 
    width:100%;
    font-size:0.8em;
    color:#000;
    padding:8px;
    margin:5px 0;
    background: none;
    border: 1px solid #fff !important;
}
```

Now I want to change the text color of "Select a Country" and of the "selected" option in the form.

P.S. The example is here: http://jsfiddle.net/V7C6w/ .

Edit:

A possible solution to remedy the problem might be:

```
.register_account
{ 
    background: #0023C4;
    width:62%;
    padding:1.5%;
}

.register_account form select
{ 
    width:100%;
    font-size:0.8em;
    color:#fff;
    padding:8px;
    margin:5px 0;
    background: #0023C4;
    border: 1px solid #fff !important;
}
```

Prove yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/V7C6w/9/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change color of option selected - jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21159032/change-color-of-option-selected-jquery)

Comment: possible duplicate of [css :selected pseudo class similar to :checked, but for for <select> elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8619406/css-selected-pseudo-class-similar-to-checked-but-for-for-select-elements)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This small line will solve the problem and give what you need i guess**

AFAIK you want to show selected item on the list with different color. here i used green for all item and white for default selection, try this one.

and it doesn't require any java-scripts, you can achieve this with simple CSS

```
.register_account form option:not(:checked) { color: green; }
```

**Edited**

```
//This line allows you to change the selected menu item color individually 
.register_account form option:checked { color: #0AD; }
```

Comment: Thanks. Is this what I wanted to do. But how can I change the color of the selected option? If I select Albania, for example, after in the menu it appears white. How can I change it?

Comment: In the question, you mentioned " I want to change the text color of "Select a Country" and of the "selected" option in the form." that's why i gave this answer?

Comment: if you select white it will show "select a country" and selected item same color?

Comment: I updated the answer, have a look, i guess finally this is what you want

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I wanted. In fact I have written so in the question because I only find answers that led to the following type of code: .register_account option [value = null], which is not completely solved my needs xD. Thanks again for your response.

Answer (score 1):

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V7C6w/5/)

```
.register_account option[value=null]
{
    color:yellow;
}
```

Read [CSS [attribute=value] Selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attribute_value.asp)

Comment: The code I tried it, but the color "yellow" is not displayed.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/V7C6w/5/ open select... "Select a country" is yellow (i use firefox 24)

Answer (score 0):

```
.register_account
  { background: #0023C4;
    width:62%;
    padding:1.5%;
   }

.register_account:hover form
    { width:100%;
      font-size:0.8em;
      color:#000;
      padding:8px;
      margin:5px 0;
      background: none;
      border: 1px solid #fff !important;
     }
```

That should work properly, use :hover, it's a lot easier.